# Standard Error For Cluster Sampling

Tags: sample-size, clustered-standard-errors, cluster-sample

A problem I've found and been thinking about for a while but not sure I can articulate properly.  Any help appreciated.

A 
survey 
is  being 
planned 
with 
the 
goal 
of 
interviewing 
$n$  people 
in 
some 
number 
$J$ 
of 
clusters. 
For 
simplicity, 
assume 
simple 
random 
sampling 
of 
clusters 
and 
a simple 
random sample of size $n/J$ 
(appropriately rounded) within each sampled cluster.  Consider inferences for the proportion of Yes responses in the population for some question of interest.  The estimate will be simply the average response for then people in the sample. 
Suppose that the true proportion of Yes responses is not too far from 0.5 
and that the standard deviation among the mean responses of custers is $0.1$.

Suppose 
the 
cost 
of 
the 
survey 
is \$50 
per 
interview, 
plus 
\$500 
per 
cluster. 
Further 
suppose 
that 
the 
goal 
is  to 
estimate 
the 
proportion 
of 
Yes 
responses 
in 
the 
population 
with 
a 
standard 
error 
of 
no 
more 
than 
2%. 
What 
values 
of 
$n$ 
and 
$J$  will 
achieve 
this 
at 
the 
lowest 
cost?

The problem I'm having is determining how to use the information given about the
standard deviation among the mean responses of clusters being $0.1$.  I'm interpreting that to mean that for each cluster mean $\theta_j$ we have $\text{sd}(\theta_j)=0.1$ but that seems to imply the overall standard error is free of $n$, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I was looking for (and the original statement of the problem) can be found here.
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/stuff_for_blog/chap20.pdf